# SQL Encryption Stored Procedures- MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008

We are using SQL Encryption to encrypt data in the database using this approach.[SQL Encryption](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/28/sql-server-introduction-to-sql-server-encryption-and-symmetric-key-encryption-tutorial-with-script/). As the main aim is to avoid data theft when the database is compromised. We will be using HTTP(s) certificates while accessing data from Server to Client.

The data is encrypted in the table level. To access the data we have created stored procedures to access them.

We have to depend on stored procedures as we have to specifically tell the symnmetric key and certificate we are using in our DB.

```
GO
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY mySymmetrickKey DECRYPTION
BY CERTIFICATE myCertificate
```

Instead of depending on the databse stored procedures can we specify the symmetric key and certificate name in our SQL Query(LINQ), to access the various tables in our DB.

We are using DB first Entity Framework approach for data access.
Any advises on these ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also looked at this issue.

One area to be careful about is that encryption generally (of course varies between encryption) roughly adds 120% to the original data. Passing this amount of information between the sql server and http server degrades the over all performance. In comparison if the data encryption is handled by the SQL database server then the only performance hit is during encryption/decryption.